# Error: Could not find or load main class . this occurs when compiling code

Tags: java

When i compile the following code it comes up with an error message saying

```
Error: Could not find or load main class javaapplication6.JavaApplication6
Java Result: 1.
```

The software that im using is Netbeans IDE8.0

```
import  java.util* ;
package javaapplication6 ;

public class JavaApplication6 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        System.out.println ("Please enter your user name!");

        String userName = in.nextline ();
        System.out.println("please enter the passcode" + userName + ".");

        int passcodeFromUser = in.next.Int ();
        int passcode = 7001 ;

        if (passcodeFromUser == passcode) 
        {
        System.out.println("welcome" + username + "!" );
        }        
        else
        {
        System.out.println("Acess Denied");        
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: the package declaration should appear before any statements

Comment: it doesn't work . I have just placed the package declaration before the import declaration and it shows a different error

Comment: @user3541130: Exactly.

Comment: yes, does this code even compile?

Comment: there's still an error when compiling the code  and its not compiling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I copy your code in my editor I found many mistakes in it.. This will work..

```
package javaapplication6 ;
import java.util.*;

public class JavaApplication6 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        System.out.println ("Please enter your user name!");

        String userName = in.nextLine ();
        System.out.println("please enter the passcode" + userName + ".");

        int passcodeFromUser = in.nextInt ();
        int passcode = 7001 ;

        if (passcodeFromUser == passcode) 
        {
        System.out.println("welcome" + userName + "!" );
        }        
        else
        {
        System.out.println("Acess Denied");        
        }
    }

}
```

Below are my changes..

> java.util*; >> java.util.*;
>
> in.nextline (); >> in.nextLine ();
>
> in.next.Int (); >> in.nextInt ();
>
> System.out.println("welcome" + username + "!" ); >>
>   System.out.println("welcome" + userName + "!" );

Comment: Just for future reference what did you edit apart from the package and import statement ?

Comment: posted my changes..in answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the package statement as the first statement of the class like below

```
package javaapplication6 ;
import  java.util.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your *package* declaration should always come before your *imports*. Normally your code shouldn't compile in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change package declaration to

```
package javaapplication6 ;
import  java.util* ;
```